# Positioning button in a bootstrap row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, css-position

I have a slider and I want to add a bootstrap row(col-md-8 / col-md-4) as a overlay, like in the image below [image]

I would like to over the slider(50%) and when on mobile it will break and be a simple row (col-xs-12)

How can I position it like that?

Comment: And what have you tried so far to accomplish this?